# Write-in option with dropdown option

Tags: javascript, html

how to include write-in option after drop-down option in html or javascript. As an example in the coding below,

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

But the user's choice wasn't in the list given (e.g. Honda). so he/she can write their option in 'others' option.

Apologies for my english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you could provide some examples of what you've tried, it will help us better understand what you are trying to do, as well as allow us to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you may want to use the `<datalist>` along with an `<input>`, which offers the functionality you're looking for; in the below example if the user types `S` then the option of `Saab` will show up which can be selected, or the user can continue to type to add a new option to the list:

```html
<datalist id="carOptions">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</datalist>

<input type="text" name="automaker" list="carOptions" />
```

While this may not be precisely what you're hoping for it does offer the functionality you require without a dependence on JavaScript.

References:
 * [`<datalist>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist).
 * [`HTMLDataListElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDataListElement).

Comment: This would do. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with jquery.

```
$('#dropdownId').append($('<option>', {
    value: -1,
    text: 'None of them work for me..'
}));
```

And just handle the case when the value is -1